# How to create formula to Google sheet truth table from another list?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of names in column A and list of dates in column B:

```
Andrew  03.01.2020
Alex    01.01.2020
John    02.01.2020
John    03.01.2020
```

And I have table like this

```
            Andrew  Alex    John
01.01.2020  FALSE
02.01.2020  FALSE
03.01.2020  TRUE
```

How do I fill the table with TRUE/FALSE of these names and dates from the first list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

> **Paste** this formula in `E2` and drag to other cells take a look at the [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oqmn3MJeiLMp1ns9OibTthMHlN5VfSWuyJLOuONf-0o/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=IFNA(FILTER($B$1:$B$4,$A$1:$A$4=E$1,$B$1:$B$4=$D2)=$D2,FALSE)
```

[image]

### Explanation

- [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/search?q=FILTER%20&from_promoted_search=true) the range `$A$1:$A$4` with  Condition 1 of [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/search?q=FILTER%20&from_promoted_search=true) function `$A$1:$A$4=E$1` where the range `$A$1:$A$4` is equal to `E$1`.
- Condition 2 `$B$1:$B$4=$D2` where the range `$B$1:$B$4` is equal to `$D2`.
- lock the row 1 to be able to drag to other cells an refrence a different column but no a different row.
- now that we have the output test it against the date on the left is it equal? `=`, this gives TRUE or FALSE output,  `[Filter output]=[value]` -> TRUE / FALSE

Comment: Looks good but why "John 03.01.2020" is FALSE?

Comment: Because it returns an array good spot

Comment: @MQ- Dont forget to upvote to benefit the respondent and future visitors [What is voting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20vote%20up,arrow%20to%20undo%20a%20downvote.)